# como Filtrar listview desde un edittext

Tags: android

Ayuda por favor soy nuevo en esto.  con este codigo ya puedo traer mis datos de un servidor local ahora quiero filtrar esa lista con un edittext como lo puedo hacer desde aqui? que me falta?   muchas gracias por su colaboracion.

```
package com.androidjson.serverupdate_androidjsoncom;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;

public class ShowAllStudentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView StudentListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    EditText editName;
    String HttpUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:80/ejemploBDRemota/AllStudentData.php";
    List<String> IdList = new ArrayList<>();

    ListAdapterClass listAdapterClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_all_students);

        StudentListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);

        StudentListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


        new GetHttpResponse(ShowAllStudentsActivity.this).execute();

        //Adding ListView Item click Listener.
        StudentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(ShowAllStudentsActivity.this,ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);

                // Sending ListView clicked value using intent.
                intent.putExtra("ListViewValue", IdList.get(position).toString());

                startActivity(intent);

                //Finishing current activity after open next activity.
                finish();

         editName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

             }

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence stringVar, int start, int before, int count) {




             }

             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             }
         });



            }
        });

    }



    // JSON parse class started from here.
    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;

        String JSonResult;

        List<Student> studentList;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
            HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(HttpUrl);
            try
            {
                httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                    if(JSonResult != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                            JSONObject jsonObject;

                            Student student;

                            studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                student = new Student();

                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                                IdList.add(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());

                                //Adding Student Name.
                                student.StudentName = jsonObject.getString("Cliente").toString();
                                student.Studenmarcador = jsonObject.getString("Gano").toString();
                                studentList.add(student);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            StudentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(studentList, context);

            StudentListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eso tendras que filtrar la lista `studentList` y luego entonces asignarle el adapter con los valores filtrados. Por ejemplo pudieras enviarle el valor del `EditText` y luego al momento de cargar la lista lo filtras:

```
private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Context context;

    String JSonResult;

    List<Student> studentList;
    String valorFiltro ;

    public GetHttpResponse(Context context, String editTextValue)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.valorFiltro = editTextValue;
    }

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StudentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ArrayList<Student> filtrado = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Student s : studentList)
        {
            // verificamos si el nombre del estudiatne contiene lo que se escribio en el editText
             if(s.StudentName.contains(this.valorFiltro))
             {
                // es valido, lo agregamos a la lista
                filtrado.add(s);
             }

             ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(filtrado, context);
             StudentListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Entonces el uso de la clase GetHttpResponse seria:

```
new GetHttpResponse(context, EditTextDelFiltro.getText().toString());
```

Aunque lo correcto sería filtrar los resultados desde el servidor pero eso es otro tema.

Comment: pero entonces tendria que reemplazar la clase GetHttpResponse que ya tengo implementada? porque esa es la que me trae todos los datos al listview como puedo implementar el filtro en esta clase que ya tengo y que se filtre al digitar en edittext.

Comment: Solo tendrías que editar el constructor y el metodo onPostExecute con el código de la respuesta. Ya lo otro se quedaría igual