# Filtrar listview dede el edittext

Tags: android

Hola buenas tardes por favor un genio que me ayude con esto que no he podido, tengo esta clase que me trae informacion de mysql al abrir la actividad pero estoy intentando filtrar con edittext la informacion cargada no se que mas debo hacer que me falta o que modifico. muchas gracias si me pueden colaborar.

```
package com.androidjson.serverupdate_androidjsoncom;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;

public class ShowAllStudentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView StudentListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    EditText editName;
    String HttpUrl = "http://gadsistem.com/ejemploBDRemota/AllStudentDataEGIPTO.php";
    List<String> IdList = new ArrayList<>();

    ListAdapterClass listAdapterClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_all_students);

        StudentListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);

        StudentListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


       new GetHttpResponse(ShowAllStudentsActivity.this).execute();

        //Adding ListView Item click Listener.
        StudentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(ShowAllStudentsActivity.this,ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);

                // Sending ListView clicked value using intent.
                intent.putExtra("ListViewValue", IdList.get(position).toString());

                startActivity(intent);

                //Finishing current activity after open next activity.
                finish();

         editName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

             }

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence stringVar, int start, int before, int count) {


                 new GetHttpResponse(context, editName.getText().toString());

             }

             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             }
         });



            }
        });

    }



    // JSON parse class started from here.
    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;

        String JSonResult;

        List<Student> studentList;
        String valorFiltro ;
        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.valorFiltro = String.valueOf(editName);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
            HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(HttpUrl);
            try
            {
                httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                    if(JSonResult != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                            JSONObject jsonObject;

                            Student student;

                            studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                student = new Student();

                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                                IdList.add(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());

                                //Adding Student Name.
                                student.StudentName = jsonObject.getString("Cliente").toString();
                                student.Studenmarcador = jsonObject.getString("Gano").toString();
                                studentList.add(student);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            StudentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(studentList, context);

            StudentListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            ArrayList<Student> filtrado = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Student s : studentList)
            {
                // verificamos si el nombre del estudiatne contiene lo que se escribio en el editText
                if(s.StudentName.contains(this.valorFiltro))
                {
                    // es valido, lo agregamos a la lista
                    filtrado.add(s);
                }

                ListAdapterClass adapter2 = new ListAdapterClass(filtrado, context);
                StudentListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////

        /////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

Comment: Juan, ya hiciste esa pregunta hace un tiempo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109721/como-filtrar-listview-desde-un-edittext. Deberias de continuar aquella y no esta. Te lanza algun error?

Comment: hola si ya hablia hecho esta pregunta y creo que tu ,e ayudaste lo que pasa esque implemente el codigo de la respuesta que me habias dado pero esta instruccion que es el llamado a la clase " new GetHttpResponse(context, editName.getText().toString());"  me da error subrayando la palabra context y dice cannot resolve symbol. debo decir que el llamado a la clase la estoy poniendo en el onTextChanged y no se si es correcto lo que hago.

Comment: No hay que repetir preguntas, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109721/como-filtrar-listview-desde-un-edittext es importante realizar una buena pregunta basandose en [ask].